# Bash Scripting: Copy files with certain file endings

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I've been trying to write a bash script to automate backing up my save files.

I've gotten pretty far but have gotten stumped at this last part. My command:

```
cp -v -r "$dir_loc/$name_pattern.*" "$backup_loc"
```

I only want to copy the files that are save games. So, `SAVEGAME.0/1/2` etc. I know you can do this with `SAVEGAME.*`

But when I try this in my bash script it says no such file or directory exists.

Any help?

EDIT: I figured it out. Thank you to @pfnuesel

I needed to not include `.*` in the quotation marks:

`cp -v -r "$dir_loc/$name_pattern".* "$backup_loc"`

Comment: You have the `*` in quotation marks, so it will not get expanded. That means, it will look for a file called `SAVEGAME.*`.

Comment: @pfnuesel Can you answer so I can mark you as the answer?

Comment: This copies all files starting with `$name_pattern`, but according to your title you only want those with certain endings? (Which ones?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the * in quotation marks, so it will not get expanded. That means, it will look for a file called `SAVEGAME.*`.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is basically sound It is therefore likely that there is another problem, a typo or something like that.  That will become apparent when you `echo` everything. For example:

```
echo "dir_loc=$dirloc"
echo "name_pattern=$name_pattern"
if [ ! -d backup_loc ] ; then
    echo "backup_loc does not exist"
fi
cp -v -r "$dir_loc/$name_pattern.*" "backup_loc"
```

(in this case, I would think `backup_loc` should be `$backup_loc`, but that is pure speculation on my part)

Comment: I forgot the second $ in backup_loc. I had it in my original script. But thanks for the answer.